# Whats of this line `eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)`'s function?

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I set the bellow code in the `wsgi.py`,:

```
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

if I use the:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

it will ignore the `8001` port of `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`?

because the logs are:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 09, 2018 - 10:48:35
Django version 1.11.5, using settings 'Qiyun02.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
(4516) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8000  # you see this is using 8000
```

If this line settings:

```
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

`('', 8000)` means : `0.0.0.0:8000`?

Answer (score 1):

[There](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/wsgi.html)  is a simple profile of evenlet wsgi, in your `wsgi.py` you use the `eventlet` wsgi as the application's wsgi.

```
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

the `eventlet.listen()` is a param of `eventlet.wsgi.server()`, and the `eventlet.listen()` means listen which address and port.

the `('', 8000)` combine the address and port. if we do not set the first param, it will be default `0.0.0.0`.
if we set the `localhost` it will be look back address `127.0.0.1`. 
and we also can set a IP address of our computer's.

We can use `ifconfig -a` to list the available IP addresses of our *nix computer. 
use `ipconfig -a` to list the Windows's.